# how to work with collections implementing IReduceInit

Tags: clojure

The `plan` function of `next.jdbc` returns collections which implement `IReduceInit`, what does that mean ? Trying to wrap my head around it, what is the difference between having a regular collection and then applying transducers to it, rather than having a coll which implements the above interface.

Also how do you work with a coll which implements the above interface, cant find any material on it.

In the below code -

```
(def results (jdbc/plan @datasource2 ["select * from cabs"]))

(into [] (map :name) results) => ["a", "b"]

(into [] (map identity) results) => gives an error - [..... missing `map` or `reduce` {row}]
```

Why does the first transducer work while the second one fails ?

Answer (score 1):

`identity` simply returns its argument without touching it so `(map identity)` doesn't "touch" the rows and they are not realized.

`jdbc/plan` requires that each row be "touched" to either select elements from it (which does not realize a Clojure data structure, it simply extracts fields from the current row of the underlying `ResultSet`), or to force realization through various hash map operations: `assoc`, `cons` (which implicitly calls `seq`), `dissoc`, `iterator`, `seq`, etc.

This is not just about collections and `IReduceInit` -- `jdbc/plan` adds an additional layer which is the "lazy" representation of the current row of the underlying **mutable** `ResultSet` object.